# how to animate collection view cell expansion to display data labels

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a collection view with images as in grid and I want to
click on an image then display labels and  changing remaining cell positions

I am using objective c with iOS 10
please, anybody can help me.

please refer to this link https://www.tumblr.com/login
in this we have to log in at the first time there are selections of categories and subcategories

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading How to Ask a good question and the perfect question. Also, be sure to take the tour and read this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want implement page like "https://www.tumblr.com/login" this site.You can use `UIPageViewController` instead of `UICollectionView` because you can customise page scroll type with animate